# JPA storing various types of files in database.(JEE6)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I have 2 questions:

1-In a byte[] variable inside an entity,can i store any type of file(images,pdf,mp3...), or is there any limitation?

2-What annotation does the variable need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, 2. [`@Lob`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)